# where is this memory leak?

Tags: c, valgrind

I have been making this dictionary "spell check" function for a while and have finally got it fully functional, except for a small error of having no idea as to where this memory leak is. When I run valgrind this comes up:

```
> ==793== Memcheck, a memory error detector
> ==793== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
> ==793== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
> ==793== Command: ./speller texts/cat.txt
> ==793== 
> 
> MISSPELLED WORDS
> 
> ==793== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ==793==    at 0x520A60F: tolower (ctype.c:46)
> ==793==    by 0x4010E2: check (dictionary.c:37)
> ==793==    by 0x400CD9: main (speller.c:112)
> ==793==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
> ==793==    at 0x4008E4: main (speller.c:21)
> ==793== 
> ==793== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
> ==793==    at 0x520A623: tolower (ctype.c:46)
> ==793==    by 0x4010E2: check (dictionary.c:37)
> ==793==    by 0x400CD9: main (speller.c:112)
> ==793==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
> ==793==    at 0x4008E4: main (speller.c:21)
> ==793== 
> 
> WORDS MISSPELLED:     0 WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  143091 WORDS IN TEXT:   
> 6 TIME IN load:         1.44 TIME IN check:        0.05 TIME IN size: 
> 0.00 TIME IN unload:       0.19 TIME IN TOTAL:        1.69
> 
> ==793== 
> ==793== HEAP SUMMARY:
> ==793==     in use at exit: 552 bytes in 1 blocks
> ==793==   total heap usage: 143,096 allocs, 143,095 frees, 8,023,416 bytes allocated
> ==793== 
> ==793== 552 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
> ==793==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==793==    by 0x5258E49: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
> ==793==    by 0x5258E49: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
> ==793==    by 0x401211: load (dictionary.c:77)
> ==793==    by 0x4009B4: main (speller.c:40)
> ==793== 
> ==793== LEAK SUMMARY:
> ==793==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==793==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==793==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==793==    still reachable: 552 bytes in 1 blocks
> ==793==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==793== 
> ==793== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
> ==793== ERROR SUMMARY: 8 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Sorry for posting the entire memory message, however I am not sure which part of the Valgrind message has the location of the error.

Below is the C code in which the error is occurring, I am assuming it is in the load or unload function.

````
```C

//for the universal hash function
#define BASE 256

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 676;

// Hash table
node *table[N];
int word_count = 0;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
//Require a search funtion
bool check(const char *word)
{
    //change to lower case to compare
    char low[LENGTH + 1];
    
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i <= (n + 1); i++)
    {
        low[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }
    
    int hashIndex = hash(low);
    for (node *tmp = table[hashIndex]; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next)
    {
        
        if (strcasecmp(low, tmp->word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
// the dividing hash function is one I cited from the yale.edu page http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/C(2f)HashTables.html having worked with.
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    unsigned long m = 11;
    unsigned long h;
    unsigned const char *us;
    //ensure element value is >= 0 
    us = (unsigned const char *) word;

    h = 0;
    while(*us != '\0') 
    {
        h = (h * BASE + *us) % m;
        us++;
    } 
    return (h % N);
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
//Bring the used sictionary to menu asap
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    
    // Open file and check file 
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (!file)
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    
    //array declaration for fscanf to read into
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) == 1)
    {
        //Create node n = new node
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            printf("No memory for node\n");
            fclose(file);
            return false;
            
        }
        strcpy(n->word, word);
        
        //Hash the word
        int hashDigit = hash(word);
        //Insert into the beginning of the list
        if (table[hashDigit] == NULL)
        {
            table[hashDigit] = n;
            n->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            n->next = table[hashDigit];
            table[hashDigit] = n;
        }
        word_count++;
    }
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
//count the amount of words in dictionary
unsigned int size(void)
{
    
    return word_count;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
//free the dictionary from memory asap
bool unload(void)
{
    //Loop to run through array
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        //to target linked list
        while (table[i] != NULL)
        {
            node *tmp = table[i];
            table[i] = table[i]->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}
````

As far as I can tell I have tried the free all of the memory in unload correctly and this is appearing from a "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)" on line 36, however I am not sure what this exactly means or how to go about fixing the issue.

I would love some advice on how to do this better.

Comment: When you paste pre-formatted text (including code) into your post, you can easily maintain that format by selecting that text and then clicking the `{}` button.

Comment: This code compiles?  I see a globally-scoped Variable Length Array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It leaks `FILE*` you got from `fopen`. `fclose` is missing.

This is where `valgrind` tells you that:

```
==793== 552 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==793==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==793==    by 0x5258E49: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==793==    by 0x5258E49: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==793==    by 0x401211: load (dictionary.c:77)
==793==    by 0x4009B4: main (speller.c:40)
```

`fopen` eventually calls `malloc` to allocate that `FILE` which must be released with `fclose` that eventually calls `free` on that `FILE*`.

---

`Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value` warning is caused by:

```
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i <= (n + 1); i++)
    low[i] = tolower(word[i]);
```

That loop reads one extra character past the zero terminator. It needs a fix: either `i <= n` or `i < (n + 1)`.

Comment: It just occurred to me that the user's ending comment is exactly what I might come away with on my first valgrind experience. Notice how prominent the uninitialised warnings are compared to the memory leak information? I think you should mention this in your answer because if the memory leak warnings USED TO BE in the output before he fixed those, then he may still have that "see promiment text and respond" habit.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret your response mainly because it enforces my point about the possibility that the user may have created a habit of response to what he's reading in the manner you suggest. In other words, if he wants to first get rid of all memory leaks, then he would have to skip the top part that we all now see here.

Comment: I have tried this solution, however it doesn't seem to in that it is telling me that here:

Comment: @Kwsswart Updated the answer for you.

Comment: ==707== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==707==    at 0x520A60F: tolower (ctype.c:46)
==707==    by 0x4010E2: check (dictionary.c:37)
==707==    by 0x400CD9: main (speller.c:112)
==707==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==707==    at 0x4008E4: main (speller.c:21)
==707== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==707==    at 0x520A623: tolower (ctype.c:46)
==707==    by 0x4010E2: check (dictionary.c:37)
==707==    by 0x400CD9: main (speller.c:112)
==707==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation

Comment: @ Maxim Egorushkin thank you so much, once more I have made the mistake of running a loop once to far

Comment: @Kwsswart: there's really only 2 hard things in programming: naming things, caching and off-by-one errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
> ==793== 552 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
> ==793==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==793==    by 0x5258E49: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
> ==793==    by 0x5258E49: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
> ==793==    by 0x401211: load (dictionary.c:77)
> ==793==    by 0x4009B4: main (speller.c:40)
```

The leak is coming from `fopen` because you aren't calling `fclose`.

Comment: I tried this, however it doesn't seem to completely stop the lines...

Comment: ==707== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==707==    at 0x520A60F: tolower (ctype.c:46)
==707==    by 0x4010E2: check (dictionary.c:37)
==707==    by 0x400CD9: main (speller.c:112)
==707==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==707== 
==707== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==707==    at 0x520A623: tolower (ctype.c:46)
==707==    by 0x4010E2: check (dictionary.c:37)
==707==    by 0x400CD9: main (speller.c:112)
==707==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==707==    at 0x4008E4: main (speller.c:21)

Answer (score 0):

You make a big array of pointers here

```
node *table[N];
```

But you never set that array to NULL.

Then you do all kinds of stuff on that array assuming it has been initialized.

Comment: The real issue here is that it's a variable length array declared at global scope.

Comment: If it were a proper statically-sized array using a true constant value (rather than a `const`), then I believe it should follow the rules for static storage duration declared objects, in which case the elements would be implicitly initialized to NULL per C11 standard 6.7.9 p10

Comment: @ChristianGibbons -- I wasn't sure what version he was using :shrug:

Comment: I don't believe the version should matter; the same rules should apply.  The only difference being that VLAs are optional in C11, mandatory in C99, and non-existent in C89, but in all cases they are not allowed for static storage duration objects.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons -- in other words it was different in each of those versions? :)

Comment: VLAs at static storage duration was non-existent in each of those versions, and pointesr with static-storage duration without an initializer would be initialized to NULL for each of those versions.  So for everything pertaining to this specifically, there should be no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with the same problem (Week 5 of Harvard's CS50 course), but the answers above only got me half of the way there.

Eventually solved it by explicitly assigning the null terminator '\0' to the remaining characters of each word, like so:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH + 1; i++) {
        low[i] = (i < strlen(word)) ? tolower(word[i]) : '\0';
    }
```